# Auto Click a button at time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

```
<input type="button" value="Start Research !" name="y1io2pp" onclick="x1ferf0(y1io2pp);">
```

Name and on click seem to be random, different characters and numbers appear when checking the same thing.

Anyways, I want to set it up in tampermonkey so that that button automatically clicks say every minute.

And actually, it would be even better if there were a way to set it to randomly click between a minute and 4 minute intervals.

Comment: Why don't you call method in interval instead??? BTW, what have you tried? **EDIT** How i see `tampermonkey`, that could explain it

Comment: `window.setInterval(function(){$('input[type="button"][value="Start Research !"]').trigger('click');}, 1000);`
Tried using this, but nothing actually happens

Answer (score 0):

```
var myInterval = window.setInterval(function(){x1ferf0(y1io2pp);}, 1000);
```

This is real basic. You can find more [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Also: if you realy want to "click" this button - you can use jQuery and it's `.click()` method.

Comment: Like I said, this part: x1ferf0(y1io2pp

It is different each time, so while this might work once, Im not sure it would work every time

Comment: And that's why you call it via `function(){}` where you can put other operations.

Comment: If they are generated randomly, Im not sure what I would put there.

Comment: W3schools is a poor resource and generally frowned upon linking to them.  Also you don't need JQuery for something as simple as programmatically clicking something.  @user3765752 replace '1000' with a variable that's randomly changed.

Comment: If it's randomly generated, just get ahold of the button in a diffrent way - it presumably sits somewhere in an element with a class _somewhere_ in its ancestors. Even if it doesn't, you can get to it - it'd just be slightly more annoying to type the full path in.

Comment: Because the onclick changes and I dont know what it will change to, I would need to actually click the button.

When trying to read up on the .click, I find a bunch of examples that can make things happen when you click something, but no example of using it to actually click a button

Comment: Using it to click...well, any element is easy `$('<selector goes here>').click()` done - this triggers a click event on whatever your selector matches - be it a button or a tickbox or anything. You just need an appropriate selector for the button.

Answer (score 0):

window.setInterval(function(){$('input[type="button"]).trigger('click');.}, 1000);

Comment: ok, I will mention that the page does have more than one "Button"

Is there a way to specifically choose the one I want?

Comment: provide the class for that button or worst case ID

Comment: window.setInterval(function(){$('.classname']).trigger('click');.}, 1000);
window.setInterval(function(){$('#idname']).trigger('click');.}, 1000);

Comment: How do you get the idname?

Comment: Provide an ID name  Else first fetch the value of the button and then trigger click

Comment: There is a `.}` in one place.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function(){$('input[type="button"][value="Start Research !"]').trigger('click');.}, 1000);
```

Look's like this is the best solution to your problem. Other ways it's unsolvable (or at last hard to).

Comment: Based on another suggestion I was trying something like that, since the start research value was the only unique bit.

Unfortunately, even with this running, it doesnt actually do anything.

Comment: You do use jQuery with that? If so, are there any errors in console?

Comment: Warning: '$' was used before it was defined

Error: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 11 and instead saw click

unclosed string

Comment: There is a `.}` in one place. Looks suspiciously like it's been copied from @user3218194

Comment: Even once I fixed the error, it is still saying " '$' was used before it was defined"

Comment: Are you importing jQuery correctly? Is it imported at the point in time you are invoking that line? Are there clashes with another library that grabs `$`?

Comment: I have no idea, Im just sticking that code in tampermonkey